# Can I freeze beef bones and use them to make a broth later on?

Tags: beef, broth, stews, bones

I am interested in making my own beef broth from bones left over from chuck roasts, t-bone steaks, etc. However I currently do not have enough bones to make a batch with.

Can I get a big ziplock "bag o' bones" going and keep it in the freezer, adding to it as I get more bones, and finally thaw + use all the bones once I have enough?

Or do bones "go bad" in the freezer, freezer burn easily, or cause other problems when accumulating the bones slowly over time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.  The advantage, as you point out, is that you can collect the bones until you have enough to make a flavorful stock.  They freeze well, but will last even longer (avoiding freezer burn) if you can remove as much air as possible from the package.  I often do with with chicken bones, necks, and skin until I accumulate a decent amount for a stock.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

But considering you can highly condense the stock (past consume to bullion), it’s not clearly why you want to do this.